# how to work radio buttons into a nesting conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I learning jQuery atm, and have to make a Loan calculator based on choices, as well as validate enteries, then output a result.

l wanted to make sure you guys knew what i was trying to do, so i have here a flow chart of what is supposed to happen:
http://i59.tinypic.com/8z02sh.jpg

that shows what is supposed to be happening. Problem is i dont know how to do this is Jquery. The radio button selector i found online (through another question on here) seems weird and i dont know how to use it. I could do this using javascript, but then i wouldn't be learning anything. So here's my code so far.

Also, im getting an error on line 14 of my JS (line 14 in JSfiddle), and i cant figure out what it is.

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/keup5vaw/1/

HTML:

```
<h1>Loan Calc</h1>
<form id="salaryForm" name="salaryForm2" method="Post" action="javascript:void(0)">
<label for="salary">Enter your annual salary</label>
<input type="text" name="salary" id="salary">

</form>


<form id="creditform" name="creditForm" method="Post" action="javascript:void(0)">
<p>Please select your Credit Score</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="radio" id="over1" value="0">
<label for="over1">Over 600</label></p>
<p><input checked type="radio" name="radio" id="under1" value="0">
<label for="under1">Under 600</label></p>
</form>


<p> How long have you worked at your current job? </p>
<input class="job" id="job1" name="job" type="radio" value="0">
<label for="job1">I have worked at my current job over 1 year.</label><br>
<br/>
<input checked class="job" id="job2" name="job" type="radio" value="0">
<label for="job2">I have worked at my current job less than 1 year.</label><br>

</form>

<input type="button" id="check" name="check" value="Check">
<div id="message"></div>
```

and JS -

```
  $('#check').click(function () {
    var salary;
    var isValid = $('#salaryForm').validate().form();
    // if validation passes, display a message
    if (isValid) {
        var salary = Number($('#salary').val());

        if (salary < 40000) {
            if ($('input[name=radio]:checked').length > 0) {
                if ($('input[name=job1]:checked').length > 0) {
                    $('#message').html("Loan Approved.")
                } else if {
                    $('#message').html("Loan Denied.")
                } else if {
                    $('#message').html("Loan Denied.")
                }
            }
        } else(salary >= 40000) {
            if ($('input[name=radio]:checked').length > 0) {
                if ($('input[name=job1]:checked').length > 0) {
                    $('#message').html("Loan Approved.")
                } else if {
                    if ($('input[name=job1]:checked').length > 0) $('#message').html("Loan Approved.")
                } else if {
                    $('#message').html("Loan Denied.")
                }
            }
        }
    });


// form validation
$('#salaryForm').validate({
    rules: {
        salary: {
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            range: [1, 1000000]
        }
    }

});
```

As per usual, thank you ahead of time, you guys are awesome.

Edit: Updated after Mottie helped out (thank you!), Still not seeing what line 14 is doing wrong, but changed the else to else if, and used the tidy up.

Comment: Use the "Tidy Up" button in the jsFiddle, you'll see that some `if..else` groupings are not closed properly. Also, if you put the cursor on a bracket, its matching pair lights up.... oh, and javascript doesn't allow ` } else () {` it needs to be ` } else if () {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your having problems with the checking if a `radio` is checked you can use this its a lot cleaner than what you are currently using and is more intuitive.

```
if($("#id1").is(":checked")){

    // do something

}else if($("#id2").is(":checked")){

    // do something else

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Although i appreciate all the help everybody gave, this comment allowed me to actually understand what was going on. Often times people just fix the code and post. This allowed me to understand and rewrite my code. Parody, thank you.

Comment: @KyleSchmelzer no problem, if this is the answer your going to use can you please accept it so others can find it easier too.

Comment: I went ahead and accepted it. Sorry im still new to this site and some of its intricacies.

Answer (score 0):

Formatting your javascript is really important to catch those type of syntax error for your self. As @Mottie said use some kind of javascript formatter to fix those issues.**Tidy Up**, 
http://jsbeautifier.org/ are better place to start up with. Here is the correct code

```
$('#check').click(function()
{
  var salary;
  var isValid = $('#salaryForm').validate().form();
  // if validation passes, display a message
  if (isValid)
  {
    var salary = Number($('#salary').val());

    if (salary < 40000)
    {
      if ($('input[name=radio]:checked').length > 0)
      {
        if ($('input[name=job1]:checked').length > 0)
        {
          $('#message').html("Loan Approved.")
        }
        else
        {
          $('#message').html("Loan Denied.")
        }
      }
      else
      {
        $('#message').html("Loan Denied.")
      }
    }
    else if (salary >= 40000)
    {
      if ($('input[name=radio]:checked').length > 0)
      {
        if ($('input[name=job1]:checked').length > 0)
        {
          $('#message').html("Loan Approved.")
        }
        else
        {
          if ($('input[name=job1]:checked').length > 0)
            $('#message').html("Loan Approved.")
        }
      }else
        {
          $('#message').html("Loan Denied.")
        }
      }
    }
});


// form validation
$('#salaryForm').validate(
{
  rules:
  {
    salary:
    {
      required: true,
      digits: true,
      range: [1, 1000000]
    }
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

modified your jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/cvynLaqf/

```js
 $('#check').click(function(){
        var salary;
        //var isValid = $('#salaryForm').validate().form();
        var isValid = true;
        // if validation passes, display a message
        if (isValid){
            var salary = Number($('#salary').val());
   
            if (salary < 40000){
                if ($('input[type=radio]:checked').length > 0){
                    if ($('input[value=over1]:checked').length > 0) {
                        //if over 600 do this
                        if ($('input[id=job1]:checked').length > 0)
                            $('#message').html("Loan Approved.");
                        else
                            $('#message').html("Loan Denied.");
                        }
                    else {
                        $('#message').html("Loan Denied.");}
                
                }
                else {
                    $('#message').html("Loan Denied.");

                }
        } else if( salary >= 40000){
            if ($('input[type=radio]:checked').length > 0){
                if ($('input[value=over1]:checked').length > 0) {
                    //over 600 do this
                    $('#message').html("Loan Approved.");}
                else {
                    //under 600 do this
                    if ($('input[id=job1]:checked').length > 0)
                        $('#message').html("Loan Approved.");
                    else
                        $('#message').html("Loan Denied.");
                }
            }
            else {
                $('#message').html("Loan Denied.");}
        }
    }
    });
 
 
    // form validation
    //$('#salaryForm').validate({
    //    rules: {
    //        salary: {
    //            required: true,
    //            digits: true,
    //            range: [1, 1000000]
    //        }
    //    }
 
    //});
```

```html
<h1>Loan Calc</h1>
<form id="salaryForm" name="salaryForm2" method="Post" action="javascript:void(0)">
<label for="salary">Enter your annual salary</label>
<input type="text" name="salary" id="salary">

</form>


<form id="creditform" name="creditForm" method="Post" action="javascript:void(0)">
<p>Please select your Credit Score</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="radio" id="over1" value="over1">
<label for="over1">Over 600</label></p>
<p><input checked type="radio" name="radio" id="under1" value="under1">
<label for="under1">Under 600</label></p>
</form>


<p> How long have you worked at your current job? </p>
<input class="job" id="job1" name="job" type="radio" value="0">
<label for="job1">I have worked at my current job over 1 year.</label><br>
<br/>
<input checked class="job" id="job2" name="job" type="radio" value="1">
<label for="job2">I have worked at my current job less than 1 year.</label><br>

</form>

<input type="button" id="check" name="check" value="Check">
<div id="message"></div>
```

i commented out your validation because im getting an error on my part

Answer (score 0):

Despite an answer already being accepted, I figured I'd post an updated script since you're just beginning to learn jQuery to maybe help you improve further.

You're way over complicating the conditionals (if/else statements) for starters.

Break it down based on the behavior you would like to accomplish and word out the functionality the same way too.

Makes it a lot easier to read if you (or someone else) needs to look at it again in 6 months.

Has Good Credit?

Has Standing Job?

Is Loan Approved?

Has Good Salary?

Here's the rewritten functional fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/q3xpsLmL/

I also merged the individual forms to clean up a little. I changed the validation to HTML 5's required, type=number, min and max since the .validate() plugin was not in the fiddle. 
Relying on HTML 5 and jQuery submit() event to validate the form.

Some more info on HTML 5 validation and pattern if you're interested: 
http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute
You can even style it using css :valid and :invalid pseudo-classes

I had trouble interpreting your logic for a applicant with a good salary. So I set it to approve if the person has a good salary and either good credit or a standing job.

If you have questions on it just add a comment.

**HTML**

```
<h1>Loan Calc</h1>

<form id="salaryForm" name="salaryForm2" method="Post" action="javascript:void(0);">
    <label for="salary">Enter your annual salary</label>
    <input id="salary" type="number" name="salary" min="0" max="1000000000" required>

    <p>Please select your Credit Score</p>
    <p>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="over1" value="over1">
        <label for="over1">Over 600</label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input checked type="radio" name="radio" id="under1" value="under1">
        <label for="under1">Under 600</label>
    </p>
    <p>How long have you worked at your current job?</p>
    <input class="job" id="job1" name="job" type="radio" value="0">
    <label for="job1">I have worked at my current job over 1 year.</label>
    <br>
    <br/>
    <input checked class="job" id="job2" name="job" type="radio" value="1">
    <label for="job2">I have worked at my current job less than 1 year.</label>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" id="check" name="check">Check</button>
</form>
<div id="message"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
//use strict to ensure variables are defined and to prevent collisions
"use strict";

//define DOM elements so events do not need refind the element.
var salryForm = $('#salaryForm');
var salaryElement = $('#salary');
var messageElement = $('#message');
var radioButtons = $('input[type=radio]');
var goodCredit = radioButtons.filter('[name=radio][value=over1]');
var standingJob = radioButtons.filter('[name=job][value=0]');

var isLoanApproved = function(salary){
    //always be pecimistic and decline unless all conditions are met
    var result = false;
    var hasGoodCredit = goodCredit.is(':checked');
    var hasStandingJob = standingJob.is(':checked');
    var hasGoodSalary = (salary >= 40000);
    /*
     * if applicant doesn't have a good salary 
     *  they have to have good credit and standing job to be approved
     */
    if (!hasGoodSalary && hasGoodCredit && hasStandingJob) {        
        result = true;
    /**
     * otherwise if applicant does have a good salary
     * they only need to have either good credit or standing job to be approved
     */
    } else if(hasGoodSalary && (hasGoodCredit || hasStandingJob)) {
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
};

/**
 * track on submit rather than click so you can catch "<enter>" key presses as well
 */
salryForm.submit(function(e) {
    var salary = salaryElement.val();
    messageElement.html('Loan ' + (isLoanApproved(salary) ? 'Approved' : 'Denied'));
    return false;
});
```